# Blazor Server: obtain and cascade down some global parameters via _Host.cshtml vs App.razor?

Tags: c#, .net, .net-core, blazor, blazor-server-side

In my Blazor Server app, I want to pass down some parameters that are available to all components, so naturally I want to define these at the root/top level.

Examples: a user's claim (user ID etc), and a user's subscription data (paid vs free etc).

Here the subscription data needs to be queried from the database.

I realized that there are actually two places where I can achieve this:

**Method 1.** I can query for all the data I need in `_Host.cshtml`, and pass it to the root Blazor `component` via the `param-Variable` syntax. Example:

```
@{
    var myData = await MyDataService.GetMyDataAsync();
    ....
}

 <component type="typeof(App)" render-mode="ServerPrerendered" param-MyData="myData" />
```

Once this is done, my `App.razor` component will receive `[Parameter] MyData`, and then `MyData` will be in turn provided as `CascadingValue` to all the child components.

**Method 2.** Alternatively, I can do the data queries from within `App.razor`'s code behind itself, then pass it down. The problem with this approach is that I found it a bit tricky to deal with the Blazor page life cycles, to ensure that the parameter value is retrieved and available in time for every child component to use, and without doing unnecessary extra queries and `StateHasChanged` calls.

So given my use case, I feel #1 seems easier and more straight forward. It guarantees that the queries are executed once per user session, and the parameters are already available by the time the root component starts rendering.

But is there any drawback of using the Razor host page this way?

Comment: I assume you have already decided for a specific solution? What solution did you pick and what kind of advice would you give regarding this? I was about to ask the same question.

Comment: @Eddi I ended up going with Method 1. I want that data to be guaranteed available once and for all, and not having to mess with page life cycles for every child component. These are stable data that should rarely ever change, and if they do, we'll ask the user to refresh or refresh it ourselves via `NavigationManager` and `forceLoad`.